# How to create and return an array of objects using protractor page object model design and promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

I'm creating a page object model and one of the properties is all the users from a table. The table has a few columns so I'd like to parse that table and create a user object for each row, then return that set to then be used in tests. So far, this is what that property of my page object looks like:

```
users: {
    get: function() {
        let userRecords = [];
        var users = element.all(by.repeater('user in users')).each(function(tr, index) {
            let user = {
                name:   tr.element(by.css('td:nth-child(2)')).getText().then(text => {return text;}),
                role:   tr.element(by.css('td:nth-child(3)')).getText().then(text => {expect(text).toBeTruthy();}),
                status: tr.element(by.css('td:nth-child(4)')).getText().then(text => {expect(text).toBeTruthy();}),
                //actionsButton: tr.element(by.css('btn btn-default'))
            };
            userRecords += user;
        }).then(userRecords => {return userRecords});
        
        return userRecords;
    }
},
```

Through trial and error I encounter one of two outcomes when just trying to print to screen each element of `userRecords`:

1. each element prints as `undefined` or
2. `userRecords is not defined`.

Just to reiterate, I'm simply trying to build an array that holds each user as an object to then be able to iterate / filter on that set in my tests.

Given the approach I'm taking, what's the ideal way to construct this user array and resolve the promises?

Edit: it's worth noting that if I do a `console.log()` within each of the `getText().then()` statements, it does print the correct data from the table. So, I do know that it's reading the table correctly.

Comment: what do you need eventually? do you need an object that contains elementFinders? or you're actually trying to return well organized values of the cells?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I'm hoping to fully unwrap the elements and the promises and the user object fields only contain the actual table values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a method that returns json, and would make it async

```
users: async function() {
  let userRecords = [];
  var users = element.all(by.repeater('user in users'));
  for (let i = 0; i < await users.count(); i++) {
    let tr = users.get(i);
    let user = {
      name: await tr.element(by.css('td:nth-child(2)')).getText(),
      role: await tr.element(by.css('td:nth-child(3)')).getText(),
      status: await tr.element(by.css('td:nth-child(4)')).getText()
    };

    userRecords.push()
  }
        
  return userRecords;
},
```

and then use:

```
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    await constructorName.users()
  )
)
```

should be as simple as that. Note, I didn't test the code, but I did use the approach in my experience. So it may require some minor modifications

In general, try to avoid `.then` - `async/await` is easier to use, `.each` - go with `for` loop instead. Also `userRecords += user;` doesn't do what you think it does (though I may be wrong here)

Comment: Yep, this did it. Much appreciated :)